# Сгенерировать id в Mysql таблице и вернуть пользователю

Tags: php, mysql, form

Есть форма на сайте, ее данные отправляются в MySQL таблицу. Все работает корректно. В таблице есть поле id. Необходимо, чтобы при выполнении скрипта:

1. он проверял значение id в последнем ряду и
   увеличивался на +1 и записывался в таблицу вместе с остальными полями
2. возвращал конечное значение пользователю на странице (после сабмита формы)

Код обработчика формы:

```
<?php

$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'database');

mysqli_set_charset($connection,"utf8");

if (!$connection)
{
    exit(mysqli_error());
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $surname = $_POST['surname'];

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO `table_name`(`name`, `surname`) VALUES ('$name','$surname' )");
    if ($result) {
        echo "Ok";
    }
    else {
        echo mysqli_error($connection);
    }
}
else {
    echo "Что-то пошло не так, вернуться на <a href='/'>главную</a>";
}

?>
```

HTML:

```
<form action="sender.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-inner">
        <div class="form-col">
            <section class="form-section">
                <h3 class="section-title">Личные данные</h3>
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="name">Имя:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" required name="name" value="" placeholder="" autofocus>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="surname">Фамилия:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="surname" required name="surname" value="" placeholder="">
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper-btn">
        <input type="submit" value="gogogogo">
    </div>
</form>
```

p.s какой тип данных указать для поля id в таблице?
p.p.s спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Поле id должно быть типа `INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY`.

Значение будет сгенерировано базой данных автоматически.

Получить его можно через mysqli_insert_id();

```
$id = mysqli_insert_id($connection);
```